# Video to geotagged images using powershell

Tags: ffmpeg, video, powershell, exiftool, geotagging

I have an MP4 from a GoPro with a gpstrack included. Now I am trying to extract a geotagged image sequence from that video.
For that I am currently using FFmpeg and exiftool; I'm open to better solutions.

I have never used FFmpeg nor exiftool before and am only a beginner using powershell so this is the script I prompted myself from GPT:

```
$skriptFolder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$framerate = Read-Host "Enter framerate"
foreach ($video in (Get-ChildItem -Path $skriptFolder -Filter *.mp4)) {
    $videoName = $video.BaseName
    $outputFolder = Join-Path $skriptFolder $videoName
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $outputFolder)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $outputFolder | Out-Null
    }
    ffmpeg -i $($video.FullName) -vf fps=$framerate $outputFolder\$videoName-%04d.png
    exiftool -p C:\Windows\gpx.fmt -ee3 $video.FullName -w .gpx

    exiftool -tagsfromfile $video.FullName -XMP:DateTimeOriginal<CreateDate $outputFolder
    exiftool -geotag "$videoName.gpx" "-Geotime=XMP:DateTimeOriginal+=0:0:${filesequence;$_*=1/$framerate}" $outputFolder\*.png
}
Read-Host "Press enter to exit"
```

I can successfully create the images and the GPX file. But then I get stuck with matching the gps data and the images. The problem I think is, that the `DateTimeOriginal` does not get copied from the original videofile. Also I am not sure if I implemented the file sequence correctly.

This is my error message I still get:

> Warning: Invalid date/time (use YYYY:mm:dd HH:MM:SS[.ss][+/-HH:MM|Z]) in File:Geotime (ValueConvInv)

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully answer your question, but here are the problems related to exiftool.

RE: UTF16 output. PowerShell is changing exiftool's output from UTF8 to UTF16 during the shell redirection to the file. This is usually a problem when redirecting/piping binary data, as it will completely corrupt the data, but as you can see, it can also be a problem with text data. See this [exiftool forum's post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=14295.0) and [this post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php/topic,8137.msg41663.html#msg41663).

RE: `DateTimeOriginal` The first problem is that `DateTimeOriginal` doesn't exist in the extracted files. All the files need to be set with a default value before the `-DateTimeOriginal+=0:0:$filesequence` command. See [this Photo.StackExchange question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/).

Additionally, the command is incrementing the default location for `DateTimeOriginal`, which will be in the EXIF group e.g. `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`. But the Geotag command is using `XMP:DateTimeOriginal`, which is a similar tag, but in the XMP group. And for what you are doing, you want to write to the XMP group, not the EXIF group.  This requires changing

```
exiftool -DateTimeOriginal+=0:0:${filesequence;$_*=$framesteps} $outputFolder
```

into

```
exiftool -XMP:DateTimeOriginal+=0:0:${filesequence;$_*=$framesteps} $outputFolder
```

The reason you need to use `XMP:DateTimeOriginal` and not `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal` is because the latter does not include the subseconds, which are required for incrementing the time for each frame.  See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160204/).

But before you can increment anything, there must be a base time stamp to increment.  This can get tricky, as most video time stamps need to be in UTC, but a lot of cameras are not aware of the local time zone and will write the local time.

Run this command to list all the date/time tags in the file

```
exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s file.mp4
```

If there is a tag that has the correct time in UTC, then replace "TAG" in the following command with that tag name. Note that this command is for Windows CMD and the quoting rules are different for PowerShell, so you'll have to figure out the correct quotes

```
exiftool "-XMP:DateTimeOriginal<${TAG}+00:00" /path/to/files/
```

If there isn't a tag with the correct UTC time, then you will have to change the time zone from in that command from `+00:00` to the correct one.  For example, East Coast U.S. would be

```
exiftool "-XMP:DateTimeOriginal<${TAG}-05:00" /path/to/files/
```

Comment: thanks for all your answers! So far, exiftool does not touch the videofiles, only the images. How can I connect the timestamp from the video to the ffmpeg created images?

Comment: This is complicated as most video time stamps are supposed to set to UTC, but not all cameras will write it correctly.  Updated answer to help with copying a base date/time.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I checked the given timestamps using `exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s *.mp4` and there indeed is not DateTimeOriginal, but CreateDate is the timestamp I am looking for. So I added that part to my code. I updated my question above as I am still getting errors. The time is UTC so I skipped adding tz hours and moved the filesequence into the geotagging command, so I don't have to call exiftool so many times

Comment: This part ` -XMP:DateTimeOriginal=${CreateDate}` is [Exiftool Common Mistake #5c](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M5).  When copying tags, you use less/greater than signs `<`/`>`.  The equal sign is used to assign a static string.  Also, in this use, you can drop the dollar sign, as that was only needed when adding a time zone (combining a tag and a static string).  Try  `-XMP:DateTimeOriginal<CreateDate `

Comment: sry for the late reply. I had already tested out both `=` and `<`. I had a warning to use = instead of < so I had switched it.  I've now narrowed down my errors to this part:
 `exiftool -geotag "$videoName.gpx" "-Geotime=XMP:DateTimeOriginal+=0:0:${filesequence;$_*=1/$framerate}" $outputFolder\*.png` which now gives me this warning: `Warning: Invalid date/time (use YYYY:mm:dd HH:MM:SS[.ss][+/-HH:MM|Z]) in File:Geotime (ValueConvInv)` and I just can't see, where my timestamp is formatted wrong. Or does have to be `+<0:` as well here? then I get the above error again to use =

Comment: You cannot chain options together.  You will have to first write to `XMP:DateTimeOriginal` using the command I listed above.  Then you can run the `-Geotag` option as a separate command.  My commands are listed for use with CMD, not PowerShell.  I cannot help with proper quoting in PS as many basic exiftool commands that work in CMD/Mac/Linux do not work with PowerShell's weird quoting rules.

Comment: running the commands seperately, I get through my script without errors and all the images get coordinates. But they're all the same. So I guess the filesequene is not working properly - I'll get into that after Easter.

Comment: Sounds like `${filesequence}` is being treated as a shell variable, not an exiftool one. Since it doesn't exist as a shell variable, it would be empty. This would be a quoting problem.